# Dynamically set the DefaultValue of a ParameterBinding in a DataFormWebPart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, parameters, dataformwebpart

In my custom aspx page in WSS I am using a DataFormWebPart with an XSL file to render some data. In order to pass values to the XSL I use parameter bindings. Specifically, I need to pass in the server host URL like this:

```
<ParameterBinding 
    Name="HttpHost" 
    Location="CAMLVariable" 
    DefaultValue="http://hardcoded.com" />
```

This works fine, but the next thing I want to do is to get the host name dynamically. So figuring out how to get that from SharePoint I added the following binding:

```
<ParameterBinding 
    Name="HttpHost" 
    Location="CAMLVariable" 
    DefaultValue='<%# SPContext.Current.Site.Url.Replace
       (SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "") %>' />
```

Now to the problem. The code works as expected if used some other place in the page, but with the above code SharePoint reports:

> Web Part Error: The 'ParameterBindings' property of 'WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart'
> does not allow child objects.

Anyone have a take on this?

I have enabled server side code according to [*SharePoint 2007: using ASP.NET server side code in your pages*](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/07/27/SharePoint-2007_3A00_-using-ASP.NET-server-side-code-in-your-pages.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying various methods of manipulating the ParameterBindings property without success I thought of how I could get the dynamic value in there using the Location attribute.

The `ParameterBinding` `Location` attribute refers to where to fetch the value from. Articles like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/05/asp-net-controls-filter-the-data-view.aspx) hints of the "Control()" option. So changing the parameter binding to:

```
<ParameterBinding
  Name="HttpHost"
  Location="Control(MyHttpHost, Text)"
  DefaultValue="" />
```

and adding the following code to my page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyHttpHost" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load()
{
  MyHttpHost.Text = 
   SPContext.Current.Site.Url.Replace(SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, ""); 
}
</script>
```

...actually did the trick!

To get to the parameter values from within the accompanying XSL file I put param elements in the root element. The param name attribute must match that of the `ParameterBinding`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
    ...
    <xsl:param name="HttpHost"/>
```

The parameter can then be referenced as any other XSL variable.